# How to play wav and record the sound coming from speaker simultaneously

Tags: python, pyaudio

I am using Pyaudio to play and record wav file in the same time. I am using Python 2.7.12 on Ubuntu 16.04. The main steps are:

1. Play the wav file and output it through a speaker.
2. Record the sound using a microphone.
3. Process both the wav and recorded sound simultaneously in real-time every certain number of frames, e.g., 512 frames.

This is my code:

```
chunk1 = 2048
chunk2 = 2048
format_ = pyaudio.paInt16
wf = wave.open(file_, 'rb')
p1 = pyaudio.PyAudio()
p2 = pyaudio.PyAudio()

# stream1 for playing the wav file
stream1 = p1.open(format=format_,
                  channels=1,
                  rate=16000,
                  output=True,
                  frames_per_buffer=chunk1)

# stream1 for recording the sound coming from speaker
stream2 = p2.open(format=format_,
                  channels=1,
                  rate=16000,
                  input=True,
                  frames_per_buffer=chunk2)

frames1 = []
frames2 = []

stream1.start_stream()

data_read = wf.readframes(chunk1)
while data_read != '':
    # play wav part
    stream1.write(data_read)
    data_read = wf.readframes(chunk1)
    temp1 = np.fromstring(data_read)
    print "source:", temp1.shape
    frames1.append(data_read)

    # record sound part
    data_write = stream2.read(chunk2)
    temp2 = np.fromstring(data_write)
    print "recorded:", temp2.shape
    frames2.append(data_write)

stream1.stop_stream()
stream1.close()
p1.terminate()
stream2.stop_stream()
stream2.close()
p2.terminate()

wf1 = wave.open('input.wav', 'wb')
wf1.setnchannels(wf.getnchannels())
wf1.setsampwidth(p1.get_sample_size(format_))
wf1.setframerate(wf.getframerate())
wf1.writeframes(b''.join(frames1))
wf1.close()

wf2 = wave.open('output.wav', 'wb')
wf2.setnchannels(wf.getnchannels())
wf2.setsampwidth(p2.get_sample_size(format_))
wf2.setframerate(wf.getframerate())
wf2.writeframes(b''.join(frames2))
wf2.close()
```

I have some difficulties doing this. I got error as follows:

```
source: (512,)
recorded: (512,)
source: (512,)
ALSA lib pcm.c:7963:(snd_pcm_recover) underrun occurred
recorded: (512,)
source: (512,)
ALSA lib pcm.c:7963:(snd_pcm_recover) underrun occurred
recorded: (512,)
ALSA lib pcm.c:7963:(snd_pcm_recover) underrun occurred
source: (512,)
ALSA lib pcm.c:7963:(snd_pcm_recover) underrun occurred
recorded: (512,)
source: (512,)
recorded: (512,)
ALSA lib pcm.c:7963:(snd_pcm_recover) underrun occurred
```

I also do not understand why I have to set the `chunk = 2048` to get `frame = 512`.

Could you help me solve this problem? If anyone has suggestions to do it another way, please let me know.

When I post this question, I cannot open the PyAudio Documentation:

https://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/docs/

The site is down.

Cheers.

Comment: I don't know about PyAudio, but the [sounddevice](http://python-sounddevice.readthedocs.io/) module has two examples [play_long_file.py](https://github.com/spatialaudio/python-sounddevice/blob/master/examples/play_long_file.py) and [rec_unlimited.py](https://github.com/spatialaudio/python-sounddevice/blob/master/examples/rec_unlimited.py). If you combine their respective callback functions into one, this should exactly do what you described. Disclaimer: I'm the author of the `sounddevice` module.

Comment: @Matthias Thanks for the solution. I am confused with the `ctype` or `dtype` in the `buffer_read` part. When I select the `block_size=512` and `dtype='float32'`, it returns an array with the size of 512 ( after I converted to numpy). But when I select the `block_size=512` and `dtype='int16'`, it returns an array with the size of 128.

Comment: I don't know, you definitely have to match `ctype` with the correct `dtype`. But if you use NumPy arrays anyway, you should use the [SoundFile.read()](http://pysoundfile.readthedocs.io/#soundfile.SoundFile.read) method instead, which does the conversion for you and gives you a NumPy array.